# Computed property doesn't update on readonly input

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an input field which by default set to readonly and when you click a button it should be possible to edit the item.

Without the readonly field, it seems that the field updates correctly.

Without it, I edit the item and when the focus is lost it reverts to the text that was previously.

```
<template>
  <input ref="input"
         :readonly="!edit"
         type="text"
         v-model="inputValue"
         @blur="edit = false">
  <button @click="editItem"/>
</template>

data(){
  return {
    edit: false,
  }
}
methods: {
  ...mapMutations(['setKey']),
  editItem() {
    this.edit = true;
    this.$nextTick( () => this.$refs.input.focus() );
  }
}
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getKey']),
  inputValue: {
    get() {
      return this.getKey();
    }
    set(value) {
      this.setKey({value});
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the store is updated correctly but the getter is not triggered.
Without the readonly he is triggered.

Could it be the incorrect way to use readonly?
Also tried this instead of true/false.

```
:readonly="edit ? null : 'readonly'"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is a better way to handle your textfield value. Use mapGetters + mapActions. Use getter value with `:value=inputValue`. And commit this value on blur via your action. Btw, pls dont change your data inside html template (`edit = false`). `:readonly` works fine with `true/false`.
Or you could use watcher. Smth like this:

```
v-model="inputValue",
@blur="toggleEgit"

...
data () {
    return {
        inputValue: this.getKey
    }
},

methods: {
    toggleEgit () {
        this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
    }
},

watch: {
    inputValue: {
          handler: function (value) {
              this.$commit('setKey', value) // or whatever you want to update your store
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see I am already using mapGetters and mapActions for changing the text field value.

Comment: Is there any reason to move from mapMutations to mapActions? the issue is that the computed get is not called, the data is updated correctly.

Comment: actions are async, mutation are not. maybe you should use watcher on your getter?

Comment: in their own example, they are using commits so I am not sure if its the issue. But without the readonly property, everything works and the getter is called.  https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Comment: srsly, use watcher instead of this set/get thing. It's easy and prob will solve your problem

Comment: Could you edit your answer, and show me an example, please?